# Post hoc (emmeans) for binomial glmer

Tags: r, logistic-regression, lme4, emmeans

I made a glmer model to predict correct responses as a function of two independent variables (2x2 within-subjects design).
Here is the head of the df with ID, stimulus, the two within-subj conditions, the dependent variable "correct" and the predicted probability from the glmer fit (added after model computation).

*Note: the correct variable was computed from the rate colum (if participants' rate < 49 and cond_A = near it is correct, if rate > 51 and cond_A = far, it is correct; the opposite for incorrect responses)*

```
                        ID stimulus cond_A  cond_B rate  correct     prob
1 5ef197dadda04d0008ba9dce    FIORE   near noncongr    0       1 0.5239730
2 5ef197dadda04d0008ba9dce    TRENO   near noncongr   19       1 0.5443476
3 5ef197dadda04d0008ba9dce     MESE    far noncongr    9       0 0.6530908
4 5ef197dadda04d0008ba9dce    MONDO    far noncongr   28       0 0.7131941
5 5ef197dadda04d0008ba9dce     VASO   near noncongr   63       0 0.4607776
6 5ef197dadda04d0008ba9dce    SEGNO    far    congr    7       0 0.6626701
```

the results of the anova are below

```
fit = glmer(correct ~ spazio*linguag + (1|ID) + (1|stimulus), family = "binomial", data = correct)
car::Anova(fit, type = 3)
Analysis of Deviance Table (Type III Wald chisquare tests)

Response: correct
                 Chisq Df Pr(>Chisq)    
(Intercept)    24.6270  1  6.957e-07 ***
spazio          0.2052  1  0.6505643    
linguag         1.2483  1  0.2638814    
spazio:linguag 14.1912  1  0.0001651 ***
```

now I need to explore among which levels the interaction is significant.

Is the emmean code correct? (why df is Inf?)

Any suggestions for improving and/or plotting the post hoc?

Thanks!

```
post = emmeans(fit, pairwise~linguag|spazio)

$emmeans
spazio = far:
 linguag   emmean    SE  df asymp.LCL asymp.UCL
 congr     0.6050 0.122 Inf     0.332     0.878
 noncongr  0.8009 0.129 Inf     0.512     1.090

spazio = near:
 linguag   emmean    SE  df asymp.LCL asymp.UCL
 congr     0.5396 0.121 Inf     0.268     0.811
 noncongr -0.0529 0.123 Inf    -0.328     0.222

Results are given on the logit (not the response) scale. 
Confidence level used: 0.95 
Conf-level adjustment: bonferroni method for 2 estimates 

$contrasts
spazio = far:
 contrast         estimate    SE  df z.ratio p.value
 congr - noncongr   -0.196 0.175 Inf -1.117  0.2639 

spazio = near:
 contrast         estimate    SE  df z.ratio p.value
 congr - noncongr    0.593 0.170 Inf  3.478  0.0005 

Results are given on the log odds ratio (not the response) scale.
```

Comment: `df` equal to `Inf` means that no finite-size "denominator degrees of freedom" correction is done (this is a somewhat unsolved problem)

Comment: PS "am I doing this right?" is not really on-topic for Stack Overflow (go to CrossValidated for statistical questions, or Code Review ...).  If you specifically want to know how to plot the results, please ask that question more explicitly.